# CMAKE opencv change build folder

Tags: linux, opencv, unix, build, cmake

i have a question (i suppose that it's stupid but i've difficult). I'm try to compile with cmake (not cmake-gui!!!) opencv. The problem is that i need to change the build folder. I give you an example:

I have the source code and the cmakelist on directory /home/xxx/opencv/

I would like to execute cmake and put the build into /home/yyy/lib_opencv/ and subsequently call make install....

With cmake-gui i don't have a problem. But i have to use the cmake command shell.

Can you help me? I hope that i have explained clearly the problem

Comment: The folder you are starting CMake from automatically/implicitly gets your binary output directory.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a directory you want build files to be in and `cd` there

```
mkdir /home/yyy/lib_opencv/
cd /home/yyy/lib_opencv/
```

Then just run `cmake` and point it to OpenCV **source** dir:

```
cmake /home/xxx/opencv/
```